# Variable error in Swift code

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an Xcode project which has some error. I had only a problem with a variable. I convert the txt string variable to int and this called txtint. When I want to make an calculation I can't because it has null value what is impossible because I give a value in function "pass" and then when I want to subtract I can't because txtint has null value.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Biophere
//
//  Created by Coder on 2017. 10. 22..
//  Copyright © 2017. Pliz Help. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textview: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var conv: UILabel!

var text: String? = nil
var txt: String? = nil
var convert: String? = nil
var textint: Int? = nil
var txtint: Int? = nil



@IBAction func pass(_ sender: Any) {
    var txt: String {
        get {
            return textview.text ?? ""
        }
        set {
            textview.text = newValue
        }
    }
            //conv.text = txt


}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    label.text = text
    txt = textview.text


}

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let textint = Int(text!)
    let txtint = Int(txt!)

    convert = String(textint! - txtint!)
    conv.text = txt
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

ERROR: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: From the code you posted, you never put a valid value in the optional "text" variable, you just use it in the viewDidLoad when it is still nil. It means that unwrapping it in the saveButton method will crash your application. 
Can you explain what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Instead of declaring as "nil" simply define as blank "" eg . var text = "" and var textint = 0 . The Complier will automatically will treat the type of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text: String = ""
var txt: String = ""
var convert: String = ""
var textint: Int = 0
var txtint: Int = 0

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let textint = Int(text), let txtint = Int(txt) {
        convert = String(textint - txtint)
        conv.text = txt
    }else{ 
        print("handle it")
    }    
}
```

**Suggestion:** Try to give variable name descriptive it is a basic thing for development.

Comment: Still yo got a crash?

Comment: Not crash but doesn't do anything

Comment: Yes, Exactly might be you are putting the wrong value. so handle the case according to the application scenario.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean, I can share my computer with TeamViewer

Comment: Sorry for that I am not able to come on Teamviewer but you can comment the value that you are putting in the text field.

Comment: Explain the functionality what you want exactly?

Comment: And I must do it all numbers?